# Select further records in hibernate pagination

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, pagination, datatables, hibernate-criteria

**Problem:** I am trying to fetch all the records available in the database(around 2000). It is affecting the application of performance. So, I want to fetch the records in batches like hibernate pagination. I am also using datatable at UI side, so, it is kind of confusing how to proceed further without adding any extra buttons on the page and using datatable pagination buttons to fetch further records.

**What I have tried:**  I have tried hibernate pagination where I select top 300 rows to fetch on startup. But, I am confused on how to fetch other records; fetching using a extra button on UI or using all new page for all the records and fetch only 300 records for this page. Also, I don't want to add any other buttons on my UI to fetch the records.

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Foo.class);
criteria.setFirstResult(totalCount-300);
criteria.setMaxResults(300);
List<Foo> fooList = fooList = query.list();
```

I am using spring mvc with hibernate.
How should I proceed?

Comment: if you are talking about [jQuery Datatable](https://www.datatables.net/), you can do this using **serverside pagination**, [Example](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) will help you

Comment: read more here [jQuery Datatable Server side](https://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code and successfully worked in my **Spring MVC + Hibernate** example,

**Service method**

**Note:** all the classes used in service layer is mentioned below

```
public UserDataPaginator getUserListByPagination(PaginatorVO paginatorVO) {
    //calculate offset e.g. for Page = 0 the first record will be 0
    //for Page = 1 the offset is 10
    int offset = PaginatorUtility.getFirstResult(paginatorVO);
    int totalRecordsCount = userDAOImpl.getTotalNoOfRecords(paginatorVO);
    paginatorVO.setTotalNoOfRecords(totalRecordsCount);
    List<User> userList = userDAOImpl.getUserList(offset, paginatorVO);

    UserDataPaginator userDataPaginator = new UserDataPaginator();
    userDataPaginator.setPaginatorVO(paginatorVO);
    userDataPaginator.setUserVOList(transformUserListToUserVOList(userList));
    return userDataPaginator;
}
```

**DAO Method userDAOImpl.java**

```
public List<User> getUserList(int firstResult, PaginatorVO paginatorVO) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);

    if(paginatorVO.getOrder() != null && paginatorVO.getOrder().equals("asc") && paginatorVO.getSortBy() != null){
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc(paginatorVO.getSortBy()));
    } else if(paginatorVO.getOrder() != null && paginatorVO.getSortBy() != null ){
        criteria.addOrder(Order.desc(paginatorVO.getSortBy()));
    } else {
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("firstName"));
    }
    criteria.setFirstResult(firstResult);
    criteria.setMaxResults(10);
    List<User> users = criteria.list();
    return users;
}
```

**UserDataPaginator.java** Class

It is used to send the response object containing,

totalnumberOfRecords + pagenumber + usersList

```
public class UserDataPaginator {
    private List<UserDataVO> userVOList;
    private PaginatorVO paginatorVO;
    public List<UserDataVO> getUserVOList() {
         return userVOList;
    }
    public void setUserVOList(List<UserDataVO> userVOList) {
         this.userVOList = userVOList;
    }
    public PaginatorVO getPaginatorVO() {
         return paginatorVO;
    }
    public void setPaginatorVO(PaginatorVO paginatorVO) {
        this.paginatorVO = paginatorVO;
    }
}
```

**PaginatorUtility.java** class

Here, I have written the logic to send the 10 records per page.If the Page number is 0 then it will return offset as 0 and 0-9 records will be fetched from database.

```
public class PaginatorUtility {

  public static int getFirstResult(PaginatorVO paginatorVO) {
      int offset = 0;
      if(paginatorVO.getPageNumber()!= 0) {
          offset = (paginatorVO.getPageNumber() - 1) * paginatorVO.getRecordsPerPage();
      } 
      return offset;
    }
}
```

**PaginatorVO.java** Class

It is used to pass in request object which conatins,

Pagenumber + TotalNo.OfRecords (used at client side to show no.of pages available) + recordsPerPage (used at client code)

```
public class PaginatorVO {

  private int pageNumber;
  private int totalNoOfRecords;
  private int recordsPerPage;
  private String sortBy;
  private String order;

  //getter setters
}
```

If you still have any query you may ask

Thanks.